# Apollo GraphQL cannot query _service

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo-server

I'm new in GraphQL. When I copied this code from Apollo GraphQL docs (and just add one more line for console.log error), I have this issue. Please let me know how to fix it.

```
const { ApolloServer, gql } = require('apollo-server-express');
const express = require('express');

const typeDefs = gql`
  type Book {
    title: String
    author: String
  }
  type Query {
    books: [Book]
  }
`;

const books = [
  {
    title: 'The Awakening',
    author: 'Kate Chopin',
  },
  {
    title: 'City of Glass',
    author: 'Paul Auster',
  },
];

const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    books: () => books,
  },
};

const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  formatError: (err) => console.log(err), // <-- only add 1 more line
});

(async () => {
  const app = express();
  await server.start();
  server.applyMiddleware({ app });

  app.listen(4000);
})();
```

And here is my `package.json`

```
"dependencies": {
    "apollo-server-express": "^3.6.3",
    "express": "^4.17.2",
    "graphql": "^16.3.0"
  }
```

Then, when I open graphql studio playground at `http://localhost:4000/graphql` -> click on `Query your server` -> I got this error on terminal

````
[ValidationError: Cannot query field "_service" on type "Query".] {
  locations: [ { line: 2, column: 9 } ],
  path: undefined,
  extensions: {
    code: 'GRAPHQL_VALIDATION_FAILED',
    exception: { stacktrace: [Array] }
  }
}```
````

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your error. I setup a test the same as you described above and receive no errors when querying the service. What is the query you used in the playground? Oh and by the way you don't need to add `express` to you project, it is already included in `apollo-server-express`.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked again and this is an error from inside GrapqhQL Studio and it was fixed now.